# Embed IP camera in web browser (CORS ERROR)

Tags: angular, typescript, cors, embed, ip-camera

Hello i'm trying to embed a ip camera using Angular 15

I am using this type of link to connect to the camera, I tried both img and iframe and neither works.
I checked the console and it gave me a cors error.
The port the camera is on is 80. I don't know if it is a browser problem but I have tried different ones and in all of them it gives me the cors error.

`<img border="0" width="640" height="480" src="http://{{user}}:{{pass}}@{{ip}}:{{port}}/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi?subtype=1">`

`<iframe src="http://{{user}}:{{pass}}@{{ip}}:{{port}}/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi?subtype=1" width="1280" height="768"></iframe>`

When I put the url in the browser it shows me the camera without problem.